# htaccess change document root to /public and prevent /public from being used

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm hosting a node app and my folder structure is like this:

```
mydomain.com
--index.js
--package.json
--public\test.txt
```

I want to treat `public` as my document root and not allow anything above it to be accessed e.g. `package.json`.

I'm currently using `.htaccess` to change the "document root":

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

This works fine and I can access `http://example.com/test.txt`, but it also means that `http://example.com/public/test.txt` also works.

How can I prevent `public` from being directly used in the URL and only used behind the scenes?

I've tried adding `RewriteRule ^public/ - [L,R=404]` to the end, but end up returning 404 for everything.

Comment: Why not simply edit your httpd.conf and change the DocumentRoot if you want to use a different directory layout?  Rewrite rules add needless complexity and compute penalties to every request....

Comment: I'm on shared hosting, so I don't believe that I can edit that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, you're not actually changing the document root here, you are effectively hiding a subdirectory using URL rewriting. To actually change the document root, you need to change the `DocumentRoot` directive in the server config (as mentioned in comments) - which will have other implications (your node app is probably dependent on the `DocumentRoot` being set as it is).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
> RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
> ```

This checks for the absence of "public/" *anywhere* inside the requested URL-path, which is not really what you require. However, the `RewriteCond` directive is not necessary here. You should instead be checking the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
 RewriteRule !^public/ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable includes the slash prefix. (Which maybe why you removed the anchor in your *CondPattern* in order to get it to "work"?)

> I've tried adding `RewriteRule ^public/ - [L,R=404]` to the end, but end up returning 404 for everything.

That's the right idea, however, by itself this will also redirect *rewritten* URLs (by the other directive). You need to only target *direct requests*. There are several ways to do this. My preference is to check the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is *empty* initially and set to "200" after the first successful rewrite.  For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^public($|/) - [R=404]
```

`($|/)` - Note that I've also made the trailing slash "optional", in that it will match either `public` or `public/` (using *alternation*) when accessing the bare directory. This is to avoid mod_dir from first issuing a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash on the directory, before sending a 404 in response to the redirected (2nd) request. The alternation (end-of-string *or* slash) ensures that `public/<foo>` is matched, but not `public<foo>`, should you have URLs that start "public" (eg. `/public-enemy`).

There is no need for the `L` flag when using a non 3xx (or 2xx) status code as it is *implied*.

**In summary:**

```
# Block direct requests to the "public" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^public($|/) - [R=404]

# Rewrite all requests that are not already for the "public" subdirectory
RewriteRule !^public/ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Note that the blocking (404) directive should be first.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This appears to be working and a viable solution if my host can't help me out. The server default 404 never seems to be displayed and instead the node app gets invoked and returns 200 -- this might be OK though as the app can issue the 404.

Comment: Perhaps you have an `ErrorDocument 404 ...` defined that calls the node app? (If you're on _shared hosting_ then I'm pretty sure you won't be able to change the document root. The other option is to "simply" move everything up a directory, as you usually have access to a directory above the document root anyway.)